# Why does this regexp not match?

Tags: regex, perl

```
my $genlog_line_1= qr{
   \A
   (?:(\d{6}\s+\d{1,2}:\d\d:\d\d|\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d+(?:Z|-?\d\d:\d\d)?))? # Timestamp
   \s+
   (?:\s*(\d+))                     # Thread ID
   \s
   (\w+)                            # Command
   \s+
   (.*)                             # Argument
   \Z
}xs;

my $line = "2018-12-14T17:32:52.236100+08:00        477637459 Query SELECT dv.mandatory,dv.optional FROM dbversion dv";

my ($ts, $thread_id, $cmd, $arg) = $line =~ m/$genlog_line_1/;

print $ts, $thread_id, $cmd, $arg;
```

Why does the regexp not match? What I expect is:

```
Timestamp 2018-12-14T17:32:52.236100
thread_id 477637459 
cmd Query 
arg  SELECT dv.mandatory,dv.optional FROM dbversion dv
```

Comment: A good approach to see where a regular expression fails is to use [Regexp::Debugger](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Debugger) to step through the matching process. In your case, you expect only a negative timezone offset but not a timezone offset with `+`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `+08:00` in your input, but `-?` in `(?:Z|-?\d\d:\d\d)?` only accounts for a negative value or values with no sign.

Thus, on the first regex line, you should replace `-?` with `[+-]?` to match an optional `-` *or* `+`. Also, since `+08:00` part should not be part of Group 1, I suggest using a *branch reset group*, `(?|...|...)`, to capture different parts inside the group into the same group, Group 1:

```
(?|(\d{6}\s+\d{1,2}:\d\d:\d\d)|(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d+)(?:Z|[-+]?\d\d:\d\d)?)?
 ^^^                         ^ ^                                         ^     ^^^^
```

Fixed pattern:

```
my $genlog_line_1= qr{
   \A
   (?|(\d{6}\s+\d{1,2}:\d\d:\d\d)|(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d+)(?:Z|[-+]?\d\d:\d\d)?)? # Timestamp
   \s+
   (?:\s*(\d+))                     # Thread ID
   \s
   (\w+)                            # Command
   \s+
   (.*)                             # Argument
   \Z
}xs;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0CSrMu/2).

Note the `?`  after the brach reset group might not be necessary if the TIMESTAMP is always present in the input.

Comment: What version of Perl is needed for branch reset groups?

Comment: @ysth [*It is available starting from perl 5.10.0.*](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3f%7cpattern))

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of your regex is that it does not take into account the `+08:00` present in your `$line`.

Change it in into:

```
\A(?:(\d{6}\s+\d{1,2}:\d\d:\d\d|\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d+(?:Z|-?\d\d:\d\d)?))?(?:\+\d\d:\d\d)?\s+(?:\s*(\d+))\s+(\w+)\s+(.*)\Z
```

**demo:**

https://regex101.com/r/fgRCv1/3